# Dynamically change HTML button amount, based on possible answers to a question in a quiz

Tags: javascript, html

So i am trying to build this web quiz/survey in JavaScript. Everything is working fine but i have the answer buttons hard coded to always display 4 possibilities.

Is there a way to change the amount of available buttons based on the amount of possible answers to each question in the quiz?

Thanks in advance :)

My first thought was to iterate over the array which contains the possbile answers and append a button element to the parent div for each choice.
I don't know the exact syntax for doing it this way, so i have no idea if it could work that way.

This is how the buttons are currently set up. (with some bootstrap information)

Only display 3 buttons for a question that has 3 possible answers and 2 buttons for a question with 2 answers.

Here is my code:

```
// This is the code i use to create an question object 
function Question(text, choices) {
    this.text = text;
    this.choices = choices;
}

// create questions
var questions = [
    new Question("Question 1?", ["choice1", "choice2", "choice3"]),
    new Question("Question 2?", ["choice1", "choice2"]),
    new Question("Question 3?", ["choice1", "choice2", "choice3", "choice4"])
];

//create quiz
function populate() {
    if (quiz.isEnded()) {
        showScores();
    } else {
        // show question
        var element = document.getElementById("question");
        element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

        // show options
        var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
        for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
            element.innerHTML = choices[i];
            guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);
        }

        showProgress();
    }
};

//And the full HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Health - Check</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div id="quiz">

            <div class="jumbotron">
              <h5 class="display-10" id="question"></h5>

                 <div class="list-group">

                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></a>


                    <footer>
                        <p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
                    </footer>
                </div>

            </div>


    </div>

<!-- Own JS Import -->
<script src="quiz.js"></script>
<script src="question.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>


<!-- Bootstrap JS Import -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're on the right track by looping over the array! To really help you though we would need to see your code.

Comment: Here is pastebin link :)

https://pastebin.com/DHvBBV05

Comment: Please post your html code too. You don't have to use pastebin by the way. StackOverflow has mighty tools to insert code right into your post! Just click on the little edit button below your question.

Comment: There's part of your code missing. Where and how is `quiz` defined? Also, `guess()`, `showScores()` and `showProgress()` is not seen in the code you provided..

Comment: Following up on what @obscure said, I would recommend reviewing [ask] and [mcve] for tips on writing a well-formed question; this is crucial to getting helpful feedback from the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript offers a nifty function called **createElement()**. As the name implies it let' you create html elements dynamically at runtime.
The other important function we'll utilize in a bit is **getElementsByClassName()**.

In your code above, the div holding the answers/buttons doesn't have an unique ID. We can still reference it through the css class it uses.

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group")[0];
```

A call to getElementsByClassName returns an HTMLCollection - which more or less is an array. By appending [0] we're referring to the first element it will find, the container div.

This div already contains elements such as span elements and a footer you defined via html. We need to get rid of them first.

```
container.innerHTML = "";
```

All we have to do now is loop through the choices array, create the appropriate html elements, give them an id and ultimately add them to the container div. This is done using the **appendChild()** function.

Here's a simplified example based on your code:

```js
function Question(text, choices) {
  this.text = text;
  this.choices = choices;
}

// create questions
var questions = [
  new Question("Question 1?", ["choice1", "choice2", "choice3"]),
  new Question("Question 2?", ["choice1", "choice2"]),
  new Question("Question 3?", ["choice1", "choice2", "choice3", "choice4"])
];

var question = questions[0];
var choices = question.choices;

var container = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group")[0];
var span;
var anchor;

container.innerHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
  anchor = document.createElement("a");
  anchor.setAttribute("href", "#");
  anchor.setAttribute("id", "btn" + i);
  anchor.setAttribute("class", "list-group-item list-group-item-action");

  span = document.createElement("span");
  span.setAttribute("id", "choice" + i);
  span.innerHTML = choices[i];
  
  anchor.appendChild(span);
  container.appendChild(anchor);
}

var footer = document.createElement("footer");
var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
paragraph.innerHTML = "Question x of y";
paragraph.setAttribute("id", "progress");
footer.appendChild(paragraph);
container.appendChild(footer);
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div id="quiz">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h5 class="display-10" id="question"></h5>
      <div class="list-group">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for explaining the way it works too! :)

Comment: Glad I could help! =)

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing your code, I would like to suggest giving the buttons a style rule like `#id{visibility:hidden}` when answering a boolean and change to visible when answering multiple choice. Hope this helps!